# Run-time error '380' Invalid Property Value

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, windows-xp

I am in the process of converting from Microsoft Windows XP Professional to Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition. There is an executable that runs fine on XP but throws an "invalid property value" error at run time on Server 2003.

According to the following link...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177088

the resolution is to edit the source code which I don't have access to. Did Microsoft ever release another fix for this error or is there a way to make both platforms fully compatible?

According to the link "A later version of MSMASK32.OCX is installed. The error occurs with MSMASK32.OCX version 5.00.3714, which ships with Microsoft Visual Basic 5.0." Is there an older version or never version that will work?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google search found version 6.00.8418 here: http://www.ocxdump.com/download-ocx-files_new.php/ocxfiles/M/msmask32.ocx/6.00.8418/download.html

Answer (score -1):

Here are the manual steps to be performed for this issue:

1) Click "Start" and select "Run"
2) Type "sysdm.cpl" in the "open" command line and then hit "enter"
3) Goto the hardware tab and then select "Device Manager"
4) Double-Click "Display adapter" and then right-click on the active video display card.
5) Select "Update Driver"

After performing this, Repeat the steps 1 to 5 to update all display adapters listed under the main "Display Adapters"

Try these steps.